# NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/io/SAXReader

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, jar, dom4j

I've currently imported the following

```
import org.dom4j.Document;
import org.dom4j.Element;
import org.dom4j.io.SAXReader;
```

I'm running the program with the help of a **`BATCH file`** but it's throwing the following **`errors`** -

```
C:\AISHU\WEB SERVICES>java  -jar webservices.jar
C:\AISHU\TEST FOLDER\formteest\fulltestxsd.xsd
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/dom4j/io/SAXReader
        at XsdToXmlActual.main(XsdToXmlActual.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.io.SAXReader
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more

C:\AISHU\WEB SERVICES>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

But it's working perfectly fine when I run it in **`Eclipse`**. I've added it as an **`external JAR`** while configuring the build path . So, in the **`.classpath file`** the location to already exists.

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Aishu/Downloads/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Aishu/Downloads/jaxen-1.1-beta-6.jar"/>
```

I've tried reinstalling **`dom4j`** but it still results in the same error.I've been stuck at this for hours, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What does the manifest of the jar file look like, and where are the library jar files in relation to your `webservices.jar` file?

Comment: Manifest - ` Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: XsdToXmlActual`

Comment: The lib JAR files are outside the folder where the webservices.jar is present

Comment: Right, so your jar file manifest should have class path entries...

Comment: But isn't it enough that the .classpath file has the class path entries ? 
So, what you are saying is, if I store my jar file (dom4j and jaxen) in the same folder, it should work ?

Comment: No. When running an executable jar with the `-jar` option, Java does not look at the `CLASSPATH` environment variable or the `-cp` option. It only looks at the classpath in the manifest of the jar file. See: [Packaging Programs in JAR Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a program with the `-jar` option, you run it as an [executable jar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html). The rules for resolving the classpath are different in that case. Java will ignore the `-cp` and `-classpath` options and the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, and it will only look at the classpath defined in the manifest file of the jar.

You have to put the necessary jar files in the classpath in the manifest file. The manifest file should look like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: XsdToXmlActual
Class-Path: dom4j-1.6.1.jar jaxen-1.1-beta-6.jar
```

Put the two jar files in the same directory as your own jar file, and then run your own jar file with the `-jar` option:

```
java -jar webservices.jar
```

See: [Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining as to why it didn't work before. My problem got resolved, and I finally understood why the error kept popping up.